# Manipulate NSString to 2D NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I have 13 textlines with the following format:
"1234 56789 1235 98765 ..." (four digits - blank space - five digits) loop 3 times.
The thing is that the blank space might sometimes not be present. like so:
"1234 56789 123598765 ..." but the separation 4 and 5 digits is still relevant.

and i am puzzled as to how do i cut and paste the content of each line to a table like data structure. This is what i have so far:

```
for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
        // take first 4 digits
        cursor_offset += 4; 
        temp = [entry substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(cursor,cursor_offset)];
        cursor = cursor_offset; // update cursor position
        if ([entry substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(cursor_offset,cursor_offset+1)] isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            // space jump
            cursor_offset+=1; // identify blank space and jump over it
        }
```

after this i go further and try to grab another 6 digits...
Is there a smarter way to do this? i thought of regex of which i'd rather not hassle with. any best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just remove all the whitespace from the string and then chunk out the pieces:

```
NSString *source = @"1234 56789 1234 1234 56789 1234 1234 56789 1234 1234 56789 1234 1234 56789 1234";
NSString *stripped = [[source componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSAssert([stripped length] % 13 == 0, @"string length must be a multiple of 13");

NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger location = 0; location < [stripped length]; location += 13) {
  NSString *substring = [stripped substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, 13)];
  NSArray *fields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,4)],
                     [substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4,5)],
                     [substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9,4)],
                     nil];
  [sections addObject:fields];
}
```

Warning, typed in a browser and not compiled.  *Caveat Implementor*

Comment: elegant. this is much smarter than the clumsy for-loop i had going on... thanks